# Know if facebook like button is clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to know if a visitor of my page has clicked the 'Like' button.
Using this code:

```
<fb:like href="[my_url]" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="20" font=""></fb:like>
```

and including the script from facebook.
I know i can use this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    //if the user click on Like
}
```

but if the user alredy has Liked my site, how can I know that?
I do not want him to unlike and like again, to run that event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in fact:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('me/likes/' +fb_page_id_or_fb_user_id, function(likes) {
      if (likes.data.length > 0) {
        alert('yaay, page liked');
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('unable to connect to fb');
  }
}, {scope: 'user_likes'});
```

Answer (score 6):

http://unbound-media.com/facebook/how-to-tell-if-a-facebook-user-likes-your-facebook-application/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
        if(response.session){
            //check to see if user is a fan of the page
            var query = FB.Data.query( 'select page_id from page_fan where uid='+response.session.uid+' and page_id ='+PAGE_ID);
            query.wait( function(rows) {
                if(rows.length){
                    //user already likes your page
                }else{
                    //user has not yet liked your page
                }
            });
        }else{
            //user has not yet logged in
        }
    });
```

UPDATE:

I personally use

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=...&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

which I got from here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

It cannot be clicked again from the page it is on

Comment: Doesn't this require that they have authenticated with your application though?

Comment: Looks like pages also can do this

Comment: Doesn't look like this event ever runs. I do not have an application, just a normal web page with the like-button.

Answer (score 1):

put the like button inside another element and add to it onclick

```
<div onclick="doSomething();">
    <fb:like href="[my_url]" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="20" font="">  </fb:like>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a great idea. Did you test it?

Comment: No problem to bind an event to the _click_ of a like-button, just use FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function() {}); The problem is to know if the button is alredy clicked on.

Answer (score -2):

Just to have an accepted ansver here.

I don't think this is possible, I eventually gave it up.

I think that Facebook doesn't want people to know if the Like button has been clicked, because Facebook doesn't want anyone to force people to like anything.

If anyone got a better answer, tell me, but right now, I think the right answer is, no, it is not possible.

Comment: No, it is in fact possible, check my answer below.

Comment: You can use a cookie when this fires up  `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    //if the user click on Like
}`